# Button Text Keeps Resetting

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I have a 100 buttons in a 10X10 grid.
They all call the same method "go".

The problem is, when I press any button its text changes as it is supposed to,
but when I press some other button after this, the text of the initial button is reset.

Here is my button code from activity_main.xml:

```
<Button 
    android:onClick="go"
    android:id="@+id/r1b1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>
```

Here is my main_activity.java :

```
package com.example.battleships;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public char[][] a=new char[3][3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void go(View view)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button r1b1 = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
        TextView op1 = (TextView)findViewById(view.getId());
        op1.setText("X");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is hundred button code i could not see in above code , there is only one button i can see

Comment: The go routine is poorly written. You re-set the main window (why?). You re-assign the view to a textview (why?). You then set the TextView's text (why?). It should be `r1b1.setText("X");`. So, I would comment out the 1st and the 3rd line in go and change the 4th.

Comment: all the buttons use the same code. the ids are diff of course

Comment: Your go() function doesn't make sense at all. You convert the same View to a Button and then to a TextView. If you want to change the text of the button, just call setText() on the button.

Comment: Bob as you said, When I removed setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); the program works as expected. also i didnt know that i could directly use r1b1.settext(); Thank you for that!

Comment: I made an answer out of my comment. So it can be marked as accepted and not be inserted in the "Unanswered" vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` from `go(View v)` method.

Answer (score 1):

The go routine is poorly written.
You re-set the main window (why?).
You re-assign the view to a TextView (why?).
You then set the TextView's text (why?).

I would comment out the 1st and the 3rd line in go and change the 4th from

```
op1.setText("X");
```

to

```
r1b1.setText("X");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 100 buttons cannot all have the same ID. Android will allow it (gives you a warning though) but it is bad design. What you should be doing is to add buttons to your view programmatically, creating unique IDs for each button that you create and setting onClickListeners as you create them.